# Custom route that match a single specific url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my mvc app, I want to dynamically generate a specific url :

```
https://myapp.corp.com/.well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json
```

This endpoint should produce a small file based on values in the web.config file. So I created this controller :

```
public class HostingController : Controller
{
    // GET: Hosting
    [OutputCache(Duration = 100, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public ActionResult MicrosoftIdentityAssociation() => Json(new
    {
        associatedApplications = new[]
            {
            new { applicationId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ClientId") }
            }
    });
}
```

And I changed the routing configuration like this :

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Azure domain registration",
            ".well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json",
            new { controller = "Hosting", action= "MicrosoftIdentityAssociation" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I expect the url to produce json like :

```
{
  "associatedApplications": [
    {
      "applicationId": "1562019d-44f7-4a9d-9833-64333f52181d"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I target the url, I got a 404 error.

What's wrong ? how to fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.Net MVC can't create route that have extension. I had to edit my Web.config to plug the MVC framework on this very specific file.

Specifically :

```
  <system.webServer>    
    <handlers>
      <add name="Azure domain verifier"
        path=".well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json"
        verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
        preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0"
     />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

From this point, I was able to route to my custom controller action using either routeconfig.cs file or the [RouteAttribute]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a route attribute:

```
    [Route("~/.well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json")]
   [OutputCache(Duration = 100, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public ActionResult MicrosoftIdentityAssociation() 
{
..... your code
}
```

It was tested in postman.